# Mac scanning ports 137, 161, 7000

Tags: networking, security, logging, scanner

I got a mac scanning for ports 137, 161, 7000 pinging the whole network.
here an image:
[image]

Before proceeding with some in depth analysis i would love to see if some of you can share some knowledge and shine some light about this case.

There the program list:
https://we.tl/t-C7BZFELVPz

OS: MacOS 13.2.1

PD: the user did no execute any network scan.

Comment: 137 is netbios and 161 snmp. Those are basic device discovery probes in the local LAN and every Mac will occaisionally scan for those, especially towards machines that don't participate in Bonjour. 7000 is an odd done though. Usually associated with either the web-server of the Vuze bittorrent client or the management console of Avira Antivrus.  I noticed Docker in the application list. Anything of interest in the running docker containers?

Comment: @Tonny you got a good lead. I'll check docker. thanks for your suggestions.